# Moving resources failed because resource group has active deployments

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

When I try to change a website's resource group in Azure Powershell, I get the following error:

```
"Error": {
  "Code": "MultipleErrorsOccurred",
  "Message": "Multiple error occurred: Conflict,Conflict. Please see details.",
  "Target": null,
  "Details": [
    {
      "Code": "DeploymentActive",
      "Message": "Moving resources failed because resource group 'rg1' has active deployments.",
      "Target": null,
      "Details": null
    },
    {
      "Code": "DeploymentActive",
      "Message": "Moving resources failed because resource group 'rg1' has active deployments.",
      "Target": null,
      "Details": null
    }
}
```

I use the following commands:

```
$webapp = Get-AzureResource -ResourceGroupName "rg1" -ResourceName resourceName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites

Move-AzureResource -DestinationResourceGroupName "rg2" -ResourceId $webapp.ResourceId
```

One solution is to delete and recreate the website but is there any other way that we can sort this problem out without deleting anything?

Answer (score 0):

Move-AzureResource is obsolete now. Try using Move-AzureRmResource.
For the error, you will have to wait till an ongoing deployment in rg1 is complete.

You could retry once the deployment is complete.

Cheers!